# SQL join query to LINQ using groupby and order by clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, inner-join

I am trying to copy this join query into linq..But I don't understand where to add group by and order by statements..

```
 select
      c.CheckID,cv.Earnings  
    FROM
      [Customers0].[pay].[CheckVendorCalc] as cv
      inner join [Customers0].[pay].[Checks] as c on cv.checkid = c.checkid
    where
      c.CheckDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01'
      AND '2022-12-31'
      and c.CustomerID = 360
      and c.EmployeeCode = '01'
      and (
        cv.TaxableEarnings != null
        or cv.TaxableEarnings != 0)
    group by
      c.CheckID,cv.Earnings
    order by
      c.CheckID

var v1 = (from cv in db.CheckVendorCalcs
                          join c in db.Checks on cv.CheckID equals c.CheckID
                          where (c.CheckDate >= YTDStartDate && c.CheckDate <= YTDEndtDate && c.CustomerID == CustomerID && c.EmployeeCode == e.EmployeeCode && (cv.TaxableEarnings != null || cv.TaxableEarnings != 0)
                         select new { c.CheckID, cv.Earnings }).ToList();
```

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query = 
    from cv in db.CheckVendorCalcs
    join c in db.Checks on cv.CheckID equals c.CheckID
    where (c.CheckDate >= YTDStartDate && c.CheckDate <= YTDEndtDate && c.CustomerID == CustomerID 
        && c.EmployeeCode == e.EmployeeCode && (cv.TaxableEarnings != null || cv.TaxableEarnings != 0)
    group c by new { c.CheckID, cv.Earnings } into g
    orderby g.Key.CheckID  
    select new 
    { 
        g.Key.CheckID, 
        g.Key.Earnings 
    };
```

Also `orderby` can be placed after projection:

```cs
var query =
    ...
    group c by new { c.CheckID, cv.Earnings } into g
    select new 
    { 
        g.Key.CheckID, 
        g.Key.Earnings 
    } into s
    orderby s.CheckID
    select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do GroupBy and OrderBy before ToList():

```
var v1 = (
    from cv in db.CheckVendorCalcs
    join c in db.Checks on cv.CheckID   equals c.CheckID
    where c.CheckDate >= YTDStartDate && c.CheckDate <= YTDEndtDate
        && c.CustomerID == CustomerID && c.EmployeeCode == e.EmployeeCode
        && (cv.TaxableEarnings != null || cv.TaxableEarnings != 0)
    select new { c.CheckID, cv.Earnings })
    .GroupBy(x=>x.CheckID).ThenBy(x=>x.Earnings)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.CheckID).ToList();
```

Comment: 'IQueryable<IGrouping<int, <anonymous type: int CheckID, decimal? Earnings>>>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenBy' and no accessible extension method 'ThenBy' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<IGrouping<int, <anonymous type: int CheckID, decimal? Earnings>>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can I use distict() instead of groupby?

Answer (score 0):

After the query:

1. Use `.GroupBy()` to group by the `CheckID` and `Earnings` columns.
2. Extract the keys for each group.
3. Order by `CheckID`.

```cs
var v1 = (from cv in db.CheckVendorCalcs
          join c in db.Checks on cv.CheckID equals c.CheckID
          where (c.CheckDate >= YTDStartDate && c.CheckDate <= YTDEndtDate) 
              && c.CustomerID == CustomerID 
              && c.EmployeeCode == e.EmployeeCode 
              && (cv.TaxableEarnings != null || cv.TaxableEarnings != 0)
          select new { c.CheckID, cv.Earnings }
         )
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.CheckID, x.Earnings })
         .Select(g => new { g.Key.CheckID, g.Key.Earnings })
         .OrderBy(x => x.CheckID)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Done update the answer. Think specify the properties will be safer.